# AttributeError: module 'disnake.app_commands' has no attribute 'CommandTree'

Tags: error-handling

I dont Operation the slash command. plz help me.

```
import disnake, asyncio, datetime, pytz
from disnake import app_commands 
    
INTENTS = disnake.Intents.all() 
client = disnake.Client(intents = INTENTS)
    
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name = '안녕', description='슬래시 설명문') 
async def slash2(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"슬래시 커맨드", ephemeral = True)
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. The error simply tells you that app_commands doesn't have the object you expect. It looks like it's something from `discord.py`, not `disnake`, which are very similar but not the same as far as i can tell.